# Laravel 4 Blade Template Engine not working

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

I am converting over a beginning Laravel 3 project into Laravel 4 and not having so much fun with the blade template engine. I know some of the stuff has changed but I still get a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to run the main page of my site. It looks like some of the **index.blade.php** files loads but the **default.blade.php** does not. Which is weird because I still have errors on my other pages but it seems like the **default.blade.php** file at least loads even though it doesnt show.

**default.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
     {{ HTML::style('css/.css'); }}
     {{ HTML::style('css/.css'); }} 
     {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
     {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js'); }}
</head>
@yield('content')
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('default')

@section('content')
<body>

</body>
@stop
```

**HomeController.php**

```
    public function showHome()
{
    return View::make('home@index');
}
```

**route.php**

```
    Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});
```

Comment: where is your default file kept? what directory?

Comment: its in the /views/ folder

Comment: Side question...are those 2 css files supposed to be empty? or is that a typo on stackoverflow?

Comment: also why are you returning the view twice?

Comment: What happensif you change your route.php to View::make('default'); and take out the yield('content').  Does the default dissplay??

Comment: yeah the css thing isnt apart of the problem it just had private information in it. And thats what so confusing about the routing system to me anyways. IDK which way to put things. I changed it to this in the routes.php page but still nothing Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showHome');..when I change the route to make('default')..I get no returned http request error

Comment: thats a good thing, that means the default is working then...because it just showed a blank page, which is what it is

Comment: and youre sure your index file is in the home directory, and named correctly?

Comment: It doesn't show a blank page it shows that new error handler with the http request error. And I'll double check but I copy all my CSS js and blade files over then I made the new changes to the blade template

Comment: just as a matter of interest...try renaming the default.blade to main.blade.php or whatever....and move it into a directory such as layouts, and then change your index file to @extends('layouts.main').....

Comment: oh yeah, and have you checked that the route is working, by removing the View::make and just putting echo"hello" for testing...

Comment: I will try the layouts.main suggestion. But if I take everything out and just throw in <p> tags it will return fine so I assume its having to do with the blade template

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showHome'); //delete everything else
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function showHome()
{
  return View::make('home.index');
}
```

**Option 2**

Try running your code again; it should work since you are not registering the controller and so it's not run. Anyway, if it doesn't, simply get rid of **HomeController.php**. Your **routes.php** is fine (if you aren't using Controllers)